# java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting the following error when my hadoop starts.

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
>   java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host:
>   hdfs://XX.XX.XX.XX:X000

and in my core-site.xml, following is the configuration

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master_Server:9000/</value>
</property>
```

My cluster is in standalone mode.

Comment: Maybe it's because your host name has underscore. That makes it an invalid host name as per RFC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As underscore(_) is not allowed. It may be the problem if your other configuration are ok.

Your configuration file should be something like

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://masterServer:9000/</value>
</property>
```